# SQL Server Subtract a value from records in the order of first to last

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a table temp with 2 columns

```
create table temp
(
    id int identity(1,1),
    amount decimal(18,2)
)
```

Sample data insert as follows

```
insert into temp(amount) 
values (100), (200), (500)
```

Table will look like

```
id amount
-----------
1  100
2  200
3  500
```

What I am trying to achieve is if suppose we deduct an amount of 150 from the table then deduction should happen in the order of Id. Which means the amount of id 1 will be 0 (100-150 =0 and remaining is 50) and then amount of id 2 will be 150 (balance 50 from previous deduction must be reduced from 200)

So the result data set should be

```
id amount
---------
1  0
2  150
3  500
```

Comment: The target column for your INSERT statement should be [amount], not [credit].

Comment: Yes. changed that

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Window cumulative summation for all previous records, save to cte for aliasing:

```
create table #a(id int,amount int)

insert #a values(1,100),(2,200),(3,500)

select * from #a

declare @sub int=150
;with cte as
(
    select id,amount,isnull(sum(amount) over (order by id rows between unbounded preceding and 1 preceding),0) as prev_sum
    from #a
)
select *,case
            when @sub-prev_sum>amount then 0
            when @sub-prev_sum>0 then amount-(@sub-prev_sum)
            else amount
         end
from cte
```

Comment: Pet peeve: [The semicolon (`;`) is a statement terminator](https://wp.larnu.uk/fundamentals-the-semicolon-is-a-statement-terminator/) *not* a "beginningator". It goes at the *end* of **all** your statements, not at the start of statements that require the **previous** statement to be properly terminated. Not terminating your statements properly is deprecated, so you should really try to get into the habit of properly terminating your statements now, so that your code doesn't break if the change is ever forced through.

Comment: @Charlieface Wouldn't that include the current row? I suspect you got deceived by the perfect alignment of "preceding" onto the right border? :P

Comment: True missed that, I think that was the reason :-)